# Organization of Large Classes in Swift Into Files and Name Spaces

Tags: swift

I have some quite advanced Swift code that was created by porting code over to swift.

It‘s three persistent collections (vector, hash set, hash map).

https://github.com/sbohmann/mutabor-swift-coillections/tree/master/collections

After the port, I added full COW support, which made me somewhat smart-ish about swift COW but not so much about swift code design and organization culture.

Each collection now resides in its own file, with all the other, non-public classes it needs on top of it (I think on top instead of below because some early version of swift demanded this).

How would a seasoned swift developer organize this kind of code?

I‘m mainly asking because unlike Java, C#, Python, C++, &c, there is no obvious way to deal with this kind of issue - I guess, that‘s due to swift‘s Objective C backgound and interoperability

Problem: the PersistentVector, PersistentHashset, and PersistentHashMap classes all have a file private class names Node, plus some more of the same names. I cannot move the Node class to its own file without renaming it, as there are no packages or namespaces in swift.

Therefore, should I:
* rename Node & al to PersistentVectorNode, ...
* leave Node & al sitting in their huge source code files
* move PersistentVector & al to their own modules, which means that I would need to duplicate all of their common, non-public code

Now that I'm back in a world without namespaces, like with C, I realize how important they are.

My C projects tend to be much simpler than my swift projects. The prefix thing from Objective C is a hack that I really would like to leave behind....

P.S. i know went with prefixes for the internally used classes. PVNode, PHSNode, PHMNode for the vector, set, and map. The whole thing is now way cleaner but using prefices still feels wrong... Maybe I'll get used to it, like in Objective C oder C. Like people did it in C++ before the introduction of name spaces.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this question gets closed due to the opinionated nature of it, but I honestly do not follow....*"because unlike Java, C#, Python, C++, &c, there is no obvious way to deal with this kind of issue [in Swift]"*. You deal with it the *same* way as you would *any* OOP language. Except with Swift you have protocols and extensions to help you too. (Or are you referring to UIKit or Xcode?)

Comment: I fear the exact same thing 

Comment: But I meant the organization into files and name spaces 

Comment: Then you *are not* speaking about Swift (or Objective-C for that matter), you are speaking about an **Xcode project**. Please, consider re-tagging your question!

Comment: I just extended the title to say as such, plus I put it into respectable AP capitalization in the hope that it might appease the Moderators 

Comment: No, it‘s not about XCode. It‘s about the usual way to organize swift xode into files and name spaces.

Comment: The usual organization of Java projects is also independentof whether you happen to use intellij, vim, or eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve but here are my initial thoughts:

Fist of all, I'd capitalize first letters of the names of your files and folders, i.e. common.swift->Common.swift. Remove spaces from folder names.

Consider breaking up your code by class into smaller smaller files and organizing it even further with subdirectories (so you dont have 800+ line files).

You can use

```
//MARK:
```

(pragma marks) to decorate your code in such a way where it will be easy to navigate in IDE

Also, you might be able take advantage of class functions.

Finally, I noticed your tests are empty, check out 'Quick' and 'Nimble' they are popular testing frameworks that might help you out.

Hope that helps at least a little.

Comment: My tests are empty? Goodness, that‘s a git issue I‘m going to fix right now, thanks for pointing that out 

Comment: About how to organize the classes into smaller files, that‘s exactly my question  The three collections each need their own private classes relative to their name spaces. What‘s the canonical way to split them into separate files?

Comment: Personally, I break these up by class.  1 class per file and any classes subclassing the same super class in the same folder.  Nothing too fancy. Some people extract protocols and extensions to other files but I think thats useless because you want option-click to take you to a meaningful place in IDE

Comment: I just moved the tests from the nonsensical directory "collection tests" to CollectionTests :D

Comment: There are no name spaces, though... Ans some of the classes inside the different collections' source files have the same names, like "Node".
This naming scheme makes perfect sense in each case but creates clashes as soon they are moved to their own file and made non-private...

Comment: In Java, I would use package private access, just to name the most widely known example...

Comment: Would you suggest renaming the Node class from HashSet.swift to HashSetTreeNode? That would really impede the code's readability, or am I just way too ingrained in Java/C#/Python's way of thinking? 

Comment: Btw. I usually strive for 100 lines max per class, so once I know the culture, this is going to be a huge refactoring task  Thanks a lot for your input about the //MARK: pragma btw. :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now refactored everything according to your suggestions, using prefices where I needed to 

Answer (score 0):

Swift style traditionally dictates one class per file. I would just split these huge files into their component classes and call it a day.

Comment: The thing is that the smaller classes inside each file have similar names - there's a Node class inside each of the vector, set, and map files... In Java, I solved this with packages, in C# with name spaces, &c.